# Keeping element height same as actual height of text

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have text in a strong element at Helvetica 75px; The actual height of the text is coming out at 55px. And the Element is 88px (because there's space under it due to line height I'm guessing.

It's for a mobile app, in the iPhone version its 75px in Ipad it will be like 140px or so, I need to make sure the height of the element just stays the height of the text!! Cause its making its containing box too big :(

Any advice anyone? I want a dynamic solution

Cheers

---

Helvetica is terrible!!!!!!!!!!         :/

Comment: a bit offtopic but.. why are you using helvetica? It looks terrible in windows, and if it can give you big problems if you don't have a distribution license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `line-height: 1em;` to be approximately equal to the font-size of the element ([JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fcp76/)).

Comment: yeh i tried that, it doesn't really help at all, maybe cause its helvetica lol